# Unable to print php variable in __ and _e function of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

here is the code which is I am using I am trying to display the custom notice on the dashboard but I am unable to print the variables in all functions so please give me some better ways.

```
$count = 'boom';
function my_error_notice() { ?>
  <div class="update notice">
  <p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'We deleted %s spam messages.', 'my-plugin-textdomain' ), $count ); ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_error_notice' );
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by " unable to print the variables in all functions"? I'm not clear what you want to do.

Comment: we use the __ , _e , _x , _n functions to translate in wordpress so i am unable to print variable in those functions

Comment: In your example you would need to have the variable passed into the function.  `$count = 'boom';`  is out of scope.

Comment: function my_error_notice() { $count = 'Boom' ; ?>
      <div class="update notice">
          <p><?php printf( _e( 'We deleted %s spam messages.', 'my-plugin-textdomain' ), $count ); ?></p>
      </div>
    <?php
      }
      add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_error_notice' );

Comment: still not working sir

Comment: Try using the `__()` instead of the `_e()` in the code you have in the comments. You want it to just return the value,  not echo it into the print_f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$count` variable is out of scope of your function, as someone else mentioned. When trying this, I also had issues using a variable called `$count` (it would only return an integer). One solution is to make the variable `global` within your function, and changing the variable to something else:

```
$spam_count = 'boom';
function my_error_notice() {
    global $spam_count;
?>
    <div class="update notice">
        <p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'We deleted %s spam messages.', 'my-plugin-textdomain' ), $spam_count ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_error_notice' );
```

Comment: sorry sir but i am still not getting the string it is giving me output :-             
We deleted 1 spam messages.

Comment: can you guys tell me another way to solve this problem

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the `$count` variable either. It must be reserved for something in WordPress, idk. Try changing the variable to `$spam_count` or something of the sort @anujrajak

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the variable change @anujrajak

Comment: Thanks a lot guys :-)